# Matrix Hit-Map Presentation Complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, entropy

I have a matrix with the values of `0`, `0.5`, and `1` which the rows and columns of the matrix show the same set of properties and these values are the dependency weight of these properties; also, this relation is not symmetric. Hence, `(i,j)` shows the dependency of the property `j` to `i` and `(j, i)` show the dependency of the property `i` to `j`.

The hit-map of this matrix is coming below:

[image]

Find the array values in python [here](https://trinket.io/python/e3996f873c).

Now, I want to arrange the hit-map visually. I mean the colors which are not blue, come together and be denser in the map.

The question is "is there any measure to show the harmony of this hit-map" and if it is, "is there any renown algorithm to optimized that measure to reach to a harmony hit-map by swapping the rows and columns? (is it implemented in python?)":

I should have mentioned that swapping the rows and columns are the just operation we can do to reach to that harmony. Also, swapping row of `i` with `j` must be done simultaneously with the swapping of the column`with`j` to remain the same meaning of the values in the matrix.

I found the [Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) as a measure of matrix entropy, but I don't know its relation with the visual harmony of the hit-map!

Comment: Well in order to implement a measure for "visual harmony" we first need a proper definition, or at least some examples with what *you* consider "visual harmony"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I mean the colors which are not blue, come together and be denser in the map

Comment: So you want to swap rows and columns to maximize the size of non-blue clusters?

Comment: @user8408080 Indeed, I want to minimize the number of non-blue clusters.